Set Hotspot to Manual or DHCP only
I created a Wifi hotspot on my ubuntu VM, The ipv4 setting method set by default is "Shared to Other computers" which means that it provides IP addresses to connected hosts and create a default NAT that force their traffic to exit the WAN interface to the Internet, I want to change that to "Manual" so I can set iptables NAT and firewall rules to force the traffic go through different interfaces instead of WAN, I can't seem to edit that because the options are greyed out
I have read that some suggest to Modify the NetworkManager hotspot configuration by doing this:
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot.nmconnection
Look for or add the line "ipv4.method=shared" under [ipv4] then change it to "ipv4.method=manual"
This didn't change anything.
Even when I do "sudo iptables -t nat -L" that default NAT rule for the Hotspot are not visible there to delete.
Any idea how to change this ?
Thank you,


